# Create MS Access database from a Python app

Tags: python, database, ms-access, jaydebeapi

I'm working with Python and interacting with a MS Access database via the JayDeBeApi library. Everything works well, I can create tables and all but the file *.accdb need to be created previously in the MS Access software

Is there a way to dynamically create the *.accdb file via my Python code?

Comment: Commonly, the rather crude approach to include an empty database with the project and to just copy it to create a new one is used. That also allows you to put things in there and use it as a template

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [msaccessdb](https://github.com/gordthompson/msaccessdb) package to create the .accdb file.

(I am the maintainer of that package.)

Comment: Or: If you need an Access file, don't create it, just write it.